# strange python index out of range

Tags: python, indexing, range

I got a strange problem with my python code

when i test it with :

```
4
Prashant
32
Pallavi
36
Dheeraj
39
Shivam
40
```

it works well but when i try to test it with this :

```
5
Harry
37.21
Berry
37.21
Tina
37.2
Akriti
41
Harsh
39
```

it fail with this error :

Runtime Error
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "solution.py", line 48, in 
    final = find(nested,find(nested,minimum(nested))[0][1])
IndexError: list index out of range

Here is the code, i dont understand why it crash, i try lot of différents solutions without any result..

```
def compteur (list,sch):
    nb=0
    for t in list:
        if t[1] == sch:
            nb += 1
    return nb

def minimum (list):
    minim = list[0][1]
    for t in list :
        if t[1] < minim :
            minim = t[1]
    return minim

def find (list,sch):
    ret=[]
    for t in list:
        if t[1] == sch:
            ret.append(t)
        return ret

def rmv (list,sch):
    ret = []
    fd = find(list,sch)
    for t in list :
        if not fd[0][1]==t[1]:
            ret.append(t)
    return ret

nested = [] 
number = int(raw_input())

for i in range(number+1) :
    try:
        nom = raw_input()
    except (EOFError):
        break
    note = float(raw_input())
    nested.append([nom,note])

mini = find(nested,minimum(nested))
for i in mini:
    nested = rmv(nested,i[1])


final = find(nested,find(nested,minimum(nested))[0][1])
final.sort(key=str)

for e in final :
    print e[0]
```

Thank you for helping !

Comment: You could break that statement into several smaller ones and narrow the problem.

Comment: I added `print find(nested,minimum(nested))` to your code and it printed `[]`. Likely your problem is in `find` and I couldn't help but notice that your return is oddly placed.

Comment: If you just dedent the return statement in `find` (right now it returns in the loop so you only process one entry) it works.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It pays to unit test your functions or at least add a few print statements to see what they return. I added

```
print find(nested,minimum(nested))
```

which printed

```
[]
```

`find` isn't working the way you want it to and after inspection, it appears to be a problem with the `return` statement inside a `for` loop. This makes it work

```
def find (list,sch):
    ret=[]
    for t in list:
        if t[1] == sch:
            ret.append(t)
    return ret
```